# Do the homotopy groups of a space determine the homotopy groups of its suspension?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to work out an answer to my [latest question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200676/is-a-finite-dimensional-cw-complex-with-the-same-homotopy-groups-as-sn-homoto)

I know that there is not a known formula for the homotopy groups of the suspension in terms of the homotopy groups of the space being suspended (e.g. spheres), but I would like to know if the homotopy groups of $X$ determine the homotopy groups of $SX$.

I suspect it is not the case, but no examples come to mind.

Comment: I suspect an answer is quite easy if you know how to compute homotopy groups of suspensions of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, but in general that will be hard.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_suspension_theorem) will probably be of your interest.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for two spaces with the same homotopy groups, but their suspensions have different homotopy groups?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come up with a counterexample:

$S^2$ and $S^3 \times \mathbb{C}P ^\infty$ have the same homotopy groups, but their suspensions don’t since $\pi_7 (S^3)$ is torsion but $\pi_7(S(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}P ^\infty))$ contains an infinite element since $\pi_7(S^4)$ is not torsion.

Answer (score 5):

Since you yourself have already produced a counter example to what you were seeking I will provide here an example of the *opposite* of what you asked for. Namely I will observe the existence of an infinite family of spaces, all of which suspend to the same homotopy type. In particular $\pi_*\Sigma X$ cannot directly determine $\pi_*X$.

Consider the wedge $S^n\vee S^n$ with $n\geq 2$. Then it holds that

$$\pi_{2n-1}(S^n\vee S^n)\cong \pi_{2n-1}S^2\oplus\pi_{2n-1}S^n\oplus \mathbb{Z}\{w\}$$

where the free factor is generated by the Whitehead product $w$. For each $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ let

$$X_k=(S^n\vee S^n)\cup_{k\cdot w} e^{2n}$$

be the space obtained by attaching a $2n$-cell to $S^n\vee S^n$ with $k$ times $w$. Then $\Sigma w\simeq \ast$ since $w$ is in the kernel of the suspension homomorphism, and therefore for each $k$ you can find a homotopy equivalence

$$\Sigma X_k\simeq S^{n+1}\vee S^{n+1}\vee S^{2n+1}.$$

In particular

$$\pi_*(\Sigma X_k)\cong \pi_*(\Sigma X_l)$$

for any integers $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$, so the homotopy groups of $\Sigma X_k$ are independent of the integer $k$. However it is not difficult to see that

$$\pi_*(X_k)\not\cong \pi_*(X_l)$$

if $k\neq\pm l$.

Comment: How does that adress the question ?

Comment: Sorry @Max if it wasn't clear to you. I've since edited in my motivation.

Comment: ok for the other direction, but how does "In particular the homotopy groups of a suspension ΣX cannot depend explicitly on those of the original space X" follow from your example ?

Comment: @Max because desuspensions are not unique. Here we have $\Sigma X_k\simeq \Sigma X_l$ but $X_k\not\simeq X_l$. It follows that he homotopy groups of $\Sigma X_k$ cannot determine those of its desuspension $X_l$.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what you wrote (I'm ok with that part of course), you wrote "the homotopy groups of the suspension cannot depend explicitly on those of the original space", whereas what you proved (which is still interesting) is that the homotopy groups of the space cannot depend explicitly on those of the suspension (the dependency relation in the other direction could very well be noninjective)

Comment: Ok, I hope this is ok now.